# How to create a score counter so that it adds a value from a loop

Tags: python-3.x

How do I pass and add a value from inside a function to outside of it so that I can create a score counter?

Hi, so I'm new to code and have been stuck on this part for a while. I'm trying to make code that will add the score of two dice rolls , then re-roll the dice and add the new score and the previous, every time the user tells tells it to. I've tried doing this as a loop but the code only displays the same numbers. What am I doing wrong, and how can I improve?

```
import random

die1 = (random.randint(1, 6))
score = 0
score = die1 + score

def onroll():
        print("Do you want to roll again?")
        if "y" in input():
            print(die1)
            print(score)
            onroll()


onroll()
```

Comment: Look up passing arguments to a function and `return` statements. If you don't know how to do this I would recommend going through a `python` tutorial.  These are some basics and if you don't know how to use them you really should sit down and do some reading/watching :).

Comment: I wouldn't use recursive calls to `onroll`. I would use a loop which only continues looping if the user enters `"y"`. The score could be calculated inside the loop, and printed inside and after the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are new to coding you would find a lot more joy in this if you follow a quick python tutorial before jumping in.

Python is a fun programming language and fairly intuitive but its only intuitive after you learn the basics :).

There are some good tutorials online such as [tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/).

That being said I will help you understand this at the basic level.

```
import random

die1 = (random.randint(1, 6))
score = 0
score = die1 + score

# A function can take several inputs such as:
# def onroll(input1, input2):
# def onroll(myInput):

# In your case you want to pass a die and a score, so lets pass that
def onroll(score, die):
        print("Do you want to roll again?")
        if "y" in input():
            print(die)
            print(score)

            # This is recursion, which is an advanced topic.
            # That being said if you want to `return` values we need
            # to add a return here.
            # and we need to re-pass our arguments
            return onroll(score, die)
        # Now we can return our die and score
        return die, score


# Now call the method
result_die, result_score = onroll(score, die1)
# And we can print the results.
print(result_die, result_score)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd do it:

```python
import random


def roll():
    return random.randint(1, 6)


score = 0
role_question = "Do you want to roll?"

print role_question
while "y" in raw_input():
    die1 = roll()
    score += die1
    print "Rolled: " + str(die1)
    print "Score: " + str(score)
    print role_question
```